# Opencv 4.1.1 Android Linking errors

Tags: android, opencv, cmake

I have an application written in c++ with OpenCV that is used in and Android SDK. Currently we're using OpenCV 3.2.0 but we need to migrate to OpenCV 4.1.1. I am trying to build it with fewer modules for different architectures.

I am using Opencv 4.1.1; ndk 16b;  cmake 3.13.2

this is the command line

```
cmake \ -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=$currentArch \ -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME:STRING=$currentArchVersion \ -D ANDROID_NDK:PATH="/Users/analivia/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle" \ -D ANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64:BOOL="1" \ -D ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24 \ -D ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \ -D ANDROID_STL=c++_static \ -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="/Users/analivia/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" \ -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \ -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \ -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING="-Os -g -D NDEBUG" \ -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \ -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_video:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_JASPER:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_JPEG:BOOL="1" \ -D BUILD_opencv_photo:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_videoio:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_ts:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_CAROTENE:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_stitching:BOOL="0" \ -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="" \ -D BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_OPENEXR:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_videostab:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_EIGEN:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_JASPER:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_TBB:BOOL="1" \ -D WITH_IPP:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_WEBP:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_superres:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_shape:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_opencv_dnn:BOOL="1" \ -D BUILD_PACKAGE:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_TESTS:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_OPENEXR:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_CUDA:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_CUFFT:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_PNG:BOOL="1" \ -D BUILD_JPEG:BOOL="1" \ -D BUILD_DOCS:BOOL="0" \ -D BUILD_TIFF:BOOL="0" \ -D WITH_PNG:BOOL="1" \ $opencvSource
```

I added to Android project but I am getting lots of undefined reference to opencv functions

Android Studio uses cmake 3.10.2

Examples:

```
error: undefined reference to 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)' error: undefined reference to 'cv::extractChannel(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)' error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the gcc as the compiler, gnustatic as STL and opencv's toolchain. 
Here is the final command

```
cmake \
    -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=$currentArch \
    -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME:STRING=$currentArchVersion \
    -D ANDROID_NDK:PATH="/Users/analivia/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle" \
    -D ANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64:BOOL="1" \
    -D ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24 \
    -D ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:PATH="/Users/analivia/Library/Android/sdk" \
    -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="$opencvSource/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake" \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING="-Os -g -D NDEBUG" \
    -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -D NDEBUG" \
    -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_video:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_JASPER:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_JPEG:BOOL="1" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_photo:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_videoio:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_ts:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_CAROTENE:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_stitching:BOOL="0" \
    -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="" \
    -D BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB:BOOL="1" \
    -D BUILD_OPENEXR:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_videostab:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_EIGEN:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_JASPER:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_TBB:BOOL="1" \
    -D WITH_IPP:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_WEBP:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_superres:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_opencv_shape:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_PACKAGE:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_TESTS:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_OPENEXR:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_CUDA:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_CUFFT:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_PNG:BOOL="1" \
    -D BUILD_JPEG:BOOL="1" \
    -D BUILD_DOCS:BOOL="0" \
    -D BUILD_TIFF:BOOL="0" \
    -D WITH_PNG:BOOL="1" \
```

Comment: Hi Ana, I am having a similar problem can you give more details on your approach? Why you took this way?

Comment: Hi Romeo, I found out that my android native library that uses opencv needed to be built with gcc and gnustatic and apparently using different compiler and STL to build opencv and my library was causing linking errors
When I used the same for both, it worked.